# Encore Global not working for legacy applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, webpack-encore

for about 2 hours I am now trying to use libaries like jquery outside of encore with global variables in my app.js, like shown below:

```
const $ = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

this method was explained here: [jQuery Plugins and Legacy Applications (Symfony Docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/legacy-applications.html)

But unfortunately I cannot access `$` or `jQuery` in script tags inside my template.

My webpack-configuration does not contain `autoProvidejQuery()` or other methods other people already suggested to comment out in order to make jQuery accessible outside.

My webpack config:

```
Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
    .splitEntryChunks()
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })
    .enableSassLoader();
```

The way I use jQuery at the end of the body (example):

```
<script>
    $('#nav').html('Hello World');
</script>
```

The resulting exception:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

In summary I have been searching for a solution for quite some time on stackoverflow and other platforms, but no solutions worked out for me so you might have a solution for my problem...

Comment: You won't be able to access `$` until _after_ `app.js` have been loaded, try putting the `script` block after the `encore_entry_script_tags`.

Comment: what would be the most efficient way for this problem? @msg

Comment: Have you set `script_attributes.defer` to false? And where is your `script` block, in `<head>` or at the bottom of your page?